# Red outputs lines - Verilog simulation

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I try to simulate in Modelsim my code on Verilog. When I'm simulating it, it shows me X(red) outputs lines. This is my code and testbench:

```
module alu64bit (
    input wire [63:0] a,    // Input bit a
    input wire [63:0] b,    // Input bit b
    input wire cin,         // Carry in
    input wire [1:0] op,    // Operation
    output wire [63:0] s,   // Output S
    output wire cout        // Carry out
);

wire [63:0] cin_out;
assign cout = cin_out[63];
assign cin = cin_out[0];

genvar i;
generate
    for(i=0; i <= 63; i = i + 1) begin
        alu1bit alu (.s(s[i]),.cout(cin_out[i+1]),.a(a[i]),.b(b[i]),.cin(cin_out[i]),.op(op));
    end 
endgenerate

// End of your code

endmodule
```

TB:

```
module alu64bit_test;


    reg [63:0] a;
    reg [63:0] b;
    reg [1:0] op;
    reg cin;

    wire [63:0] s;
    wire cout;

    alu64bit uut (
        .a(a),  
        .b(b),
        .cin(cin), 
        .op(op),
        .s(s), 
        .cout(cout)
    );
    
    initial begin
        a = 64'hffffffffffffffff;
        b = 64'h0000000000000000;
        cin = 0;
        op[1] = 1;
        op[0] = 0;
        #100;
        
        end 

endmodule
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpc2a.png)

Can somebody help me with this problem? Thank You!

Comment: You don't show the code for `alu1bit`. Also, `cin_out` need to be 65 bits wide.

Comment: The problem seems to be that op is undriven in the alu64bit but I am not sure why given the code you posted.

Comment: you have a mess with `cin` in alu64bit. It is an input port, but you assign to it. most likely it it's value is 'x' and causes other issues. Check it.